# Silverlight application get randomly stucks after loading plugin

Tags: c#, caching, silverlight-5.0

I've been experiencing a rather weird and annoying bug with my Silverlight application.

My environment:
Silverlight  5 // C# .net 4 // DB: Oracle 10g // Debug with IIS and Chrome

I recently migrated to SL5 and never experinced this kind of prolems with SL4.
On launch I fill server cache with the data that will be needed tu run the application smoothly (for the user). The initialization, during which I display the wait indicator, is done once. (for the first user to log in)

However, in debug (as well as on a production-like server) sometimes the application gets stuck in a bizarre state:
 - I can see the general layout of the application, but can't click on anything
 - The whole layout is "whiter"
It seems like a modal window should be there, hence the disabled and white layout. I can't see anything relevant in Fiddler...
Since a image worths a thousand words: [Screenshot KO](http://hpics.li/9593cbf)


As anyone experienced that before?

Thanks,

Etienne.

Comment: I've seen that before. Generally it's when the browser detects that the plugin is unresponsive (too heavy or infinite loop on the main UI thread) and non-interactable. Can you double-check that you aren't hanging the main thread and/or move the initialization work to a background thread?

Comment: Since I'm quite in a rush for a new version, I had to found a "workaround". <br>When I inti my application a popup (ChildWindow) is there to make the user wait. I removed the popup and eveything works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got time to dig in.
The solution was to make ALL our pop up windows (including warning and error windows) inherit of the folowing class:

```
 /// <summary>
/// ALL THE APP POP UP HAVE TO INHERIT from ChildWindowEx
/// prevents the greyish app bug
/// </summary>
public class ChildWindowEx : ChildWindow
{
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true);
    }
}
```